# Cordova Image file URL save to SQL

Tags: sql, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I have this app where I take an image , save it locally to the filesytem then display it 'temporarily' , I'm trying to save the file url for the image on SQL ( sqlcipher ) then assign id for each image and display them 'permanently' , eventually upload them to server . So far I can capture the image and save them on filesytem ( cache folder ) for the app. I tried couple of ways to implement the sql part , but still don't know how to connect it to the dom (html) and make it work.

Any help will be appreciated.

Controller

```
 $cordovaCamera.getPicture(options).then(function(imagePath) {
    // Grab the file name of the photo in the temporary directory

    var currentName = imagePath.replace(/^.*[\\\/]/, '');
    alert(currentName);

    //Create a new name for the photo to avoid duplication

    var d = new Date(),
        n = d.getTime(),
        newFileName = n + ".jpg";

    // If you are trying to load image from the gallery on Android we need special treatment!

    if ($cordovaDevice.getPlatform() == 'Android' && sourceType === Camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY) {
        window.FilePath.resolveNativePath(imagePath, function(entry) {
            window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(entry, success, fail);

            function fail(e) {
                console.error('Error: ', e);
            }

            function success(fileEntry) {
                var namePath = fileEntry.nativeURL.substr(0, fileEntry.nativeURL.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
                // Only copy because of access rights
                $cordovaFile.copyFile(namePath, fileEntry.name, cordova.file.dataDirectory, newFileName).then(function(success) {
                    $scope.image = newFileName;
                }, function(error) {
                    $scope.showAlert('Error', error.exception);
                });
                alert(fileEntry.nativeURL);

            };
        });
    } else {
        var namePath = imagePath.substr(0, imagePath.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
        // Move the file to permanent storage
        $cordovaFile.moveFile(namePath, currentName, cordova.file.dataDirectory, newFileName).then(function(success) {
            $scope.image = newFileName;
        }, function(error) {
            $scope.showAlert('Error', error.exception);
        });
        alert(namePath);

    }
},
function(err) {
    // Not always an error, maybe cancel was pressed...
})
};

 // Returns the local path inside the app for an image
  $scope.pathForImage = function(image) {
  if (image === null) {
    return '';
   } else {
    return cordova.file.dataDirectory + image;

}
  };
```

SQL

```
     $cordovaSQLite.execute(_db, 'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Image' +
      '(' +
      'g_id integer primary key, ' +
      'imageUrl TEXT,' +
      'timeStamp TEXT' +
      ')');

  function SaveImgInDB(jsonImgObj) {
      var imgObj = {};
      imgObj.g_id = DataCheck(jsonImgObj.g_id);
      imgObj.imageUrl = DataCheck(jsonImgObj.imageUrl);
      imgObj.timeStamp = DataCheck(jsonImgObj.timeStamp);

      InsertImgInDB(imgObj);
  }

  function InsertImgInDB(imgObj) {
      var query = 'INSERT INTO Image' +
          '(' +
          'g_id integer primary key, ' +
          'imageUrl TEXT,' +
          'timeStamp TEXT' +
          ')';
      $cordovaSQLite.execute(_db, query, [
          imgObj.g_id,
          imgObj.imageUrl,
          imgObj.timeStamp
      ]).then(function(res) {
              Logger.log("Img Insert / ID -> " + res.insertId);
          },
          function(err) {
              Logger.log('img Insert' + err.message);
          });
  }


  .factory('Images', function($cordovaSQLite) {

      var images = [];

      return {
          all: function() {


              $cordovaSQLite.execute(_db, "SELECT * FROM Image")
                  .then(function(res) {
                          for (var i = 0; i < res.rows.length; i++) {
                              images.push(res.rows.item(i));
                          }
                      },
                      function(err) {
                          console.log("Error");
                      })

              return image;
          },
          remove: function(ImageId) {
              $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, "DELETE FROM Images WHERE id=?", [ImageId])
                  .then(function(res) {
                          console.log("Deleted");
                      },
                      function(err) {
                          console.log("Error");
                      })

          }
      }
  })
```

HTML

```
<ion-scroll>
    <img ng-src="{{pathForImage(image)}}" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;" />
</ion-scroll>
```

Answer (score 0):

To get it the image data to your DOM, In your controller call the Image.all() method to get the images. Since, it is a SQL call, it must be wrapped in a promise like so :

```
all: function() {
    return $q(function(resolve, reject){
        $cordovaSQLite.execute(_db, "SELECT * FROM Image")
                  .then(function(res) {
                          for (var i = 0; i < res.rows.length; i++) {
                              images.push(res.rows.item(i));
                          }
                          return resolve(images);//sending back images once the sql loads the dataset
                      },
                      function(err) {
                          console.log("Error");
                          return reject(err);//throwing error when there is a db error
                      })

    })

}
```

In your controller call the factory and bind the result to a scope variable :

```
Image.all()//Image.all will return promise since we have impleented using $q service
    .then(function(images){
         $scope.images = images;//attach the image data to scope variable which can be bound to the DOM.
    })
    .catch(function(error){
         alert("couldnt load images");
    })
```

In you html : 
EDIT :

```
<ion-scroll>
    <img ng-repeat="image in images" ng-src="pathForImage(image)" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;" />//repeat img tag for all images and bind their urls to the img tag
</ion-scroll>
```

Comment: Hi , thanks for your answer , but i'm using File url to get the image , through pathForImage function

Comment: also in which part in the controller should I bind the promise

Comment: You can call the promise in the begining of the controller itself.

Comment: sorry, so issue in edits.. basically pass the image you get from ngrepeat to the pathForImage function.. Also, if you found my answer helpful, mark it as correct :-)

Comment: Ok I will , last thing , in which part in the controller should I bind the promise

Comment: what do you get when you console.log($scope.images) ?

Comment: I tried to call it on the top as u said .
I got this error TypeError: Image.all is not a function

Comment: Have you injected the 'Image' factory into your controller? like .controller('yourcontrollername',['Image', function(Image){ //Your controller code }])

Comment: Can you show me how to use function insert and save image within the contorller and html , i won't use the factory anymore , I just wanna save the image path inside the sql so i can still be displayed once i log out and in again

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41890369/save-cordova-camera-image-file-url-into-sql